# Where's my avatar gone?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

My answer here [Initializing structs in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838107/initialising-structs-in-c/2838228#2838228) sems to have lost my avatar - a bug?

Comment: Strange.  The page seems to think your answer is CW, but when I open the editor the CW box is unchecked.

Comment: @Bill The answer is intended to be CW, and I checked the CW box.

Comment: It's working now.

Comment: @Neil: Oh, well there you go then.  Your avatar doesn't show up on CW posts.

Comment: How does someone like @Neil not have noticed this by now @Bill? Is this a very poor always-friday-in-iceland question? ;)

Comment: @Earlz: Maybe he was just leading us on...

Comment: Aargh - must have been having a momentary blackout. But so it seems was litb!

Comment: @Neil i had no idea they aren't shown -.-

Answer (score 7):

When you make a Community Wiki post your avatar is not shown.